# Change one weight in a list and adjust all other weights accordingly so that the sum of the list is 1.0 again

Tags: python, list

I have a list of weights which all have a value range between 0.0 and 1.0. The sum of the values in list should be always 1.0.

Now I would like to write a function in which I can change one weight from the list by a certain value (positive or negative). The remaining weights of the lst should be adjusted evenly, so that the sum of the list result in 1.0 again at the end.

Example:

```
weights = [0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1]
```

If I increase the second entry of the list by 0.3, the resulting list should look like this:

```
weights = [0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.0]
```

I've tried with the following function:

```
def change_weight(weights, index, value):
  result = []
  weight_to_change = weights[index] + value
  weights.pop(index)
  for i, weight in enumerate(weights):
    if i == index:
      result.append(weight_to_change)

    result.append(weight - value/len(weights))

  return result
```

This works perfectly for the example above:

```
weights = [0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1]
print(change_weight(weights, 1, 0.3))
# like expected: [0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.0]
```

However, if I want to change the second weight about 0.5. The the last element of the list will get a negative value:

```
weights = [0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1]
print(change_weight(weights, 1, 0.5))
```

results in `[0.33, 0.7, 0.03, -0.07]`

However, I do not want any negative values in the list. Such values should instead be set to 0.0 and the remainder added or subtracted evenly to the other values.

Does anyone have an idea how I can implement this?

Comment: Why don't normalize the other weights by their sum divided by `(1-new_weight)`?

Comment: Rounding to two digits (which can be done with `round` rather than the hack of casting it to a formatted string then casting it back to a float) can interfere with the property of summing to 1. There really isn't any good reason to limit the precision of your probabilities. When you *display* the result you can format it, but why not use the full power of floats in your computations?

Comment: @RemiCuingnet I don't understand exactly how you mean that. Could you give me a short example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes, you are absolutely right. The casting makes no sense.

Comment: The idea is to multiply the other weights by a normalizing constant, where that constant is chosen so that the total of these new weights is 1 - new_weight (where new_weight is the new weight at the chosen index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a implementation of the idea of @RemiCuingnet :

```
def change_weight(weights, index, value):
    new_weight = weights[index] + value
    old_sum = sum(w for i,w in enumerate(weights) if i != index)
    new_weights = []
    for i,w in enumerate(weights):
        if i == index:
            new_weights.append(new_weight)
        else:
            new_weights.append(w*(1-new_weight)/old_sum)
    return new_weights
```

For example

```
print(change_weight([0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1],1,.3))
print(change_weight([0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1],1,.5))
```

Output:

```
[0.3125, 0.5, 0.12500000000000003, 0.06250000000000001]
[0.18750000000000006, 0.7, 0.07500000000000002, 0.03750000000000001]
```